# laravel 9 - Fill missing dates in collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table "calendar", with columns: id / property_id / price / date

Date column, is the init of range dates, for example, with this data table:

```
property_id | price  |   date

    1       |  100   | 2022-08-01
    1       |  110   | 2022-08-10
    1       |  111   | 2022-08-15
    1       |  10    | 2022-08-16
```

The range from 2022-08-01 to 2022-08-09 have the price of 100

First, I make a query for get all lines between 2 dates, and if first date don't is the init date, I make another query for get it and append to collection:

```
$res = Calendar::whereBetween('date', [$initDate, $endDate])                            
                        ->where('property_id ', $property)->get();

if($res->first()->date!= $initDate){

    $resInicio = Calendar::where('date', '<=', $initDate)                        
                    ->where('property_id ', $property)->first();
    $res->prepend($resInicio);
}
```

Now, for example, with init date 2022-08-03 to final date 2022-08-14 I have a collection with this 2 rows:

```
1       |  100   | 2022-08-01
1       |  110   | 2022-08-10
```

It's possible to refill this collection with values for every day? And delete out of range dates, like 2022-08-01 and 2022-08-02.

I need the final collection to look like this:

```
1       |  100   | 2022-08-03
1       |  100   | 2022-08-04
1       |  100   | 2022-08-05
1       |  100   | 2022-08-06
1       |  100   | 2022-08-07
1       |  100   | 2022-08-08
1       |  100   | 2022-08-09
1       |  110   | 2022-08-10
1       |  110   | 2022-08-11
1       |  110   | 2022-08-12
1       |  110   | 2022-08-13
1       |  110   | 2022-08-14
```

Comment: In the if statement, can't you just create a new Collection between `$resInicio` and `$initDate` and then merge the two?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. The query within the if is only to collect the range before the start, in case it does not exist in the first query. In the example it returns only 2 ranges, but they could be 100 :(

Comment: I think I may have misread, apologies. I'm now confused why you are fetching `$resInicio` if you then want to delete it in the final output. I think the answer below looks to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting earlier dates is because you're using `<=` here - `Calendar::where('date', '<=', $initDate)                         ->where('property_id ', $property)->first();`

Start by just getting the dates within the range you want, then i'd use Carbon to create a date range, then loop it and add missing rows to the database or collection (this is untested, but should give you the right idea):

```
use Carbon/Carbon;

...

$res = Calendar::whereBetween('date', [$initDate, $endDate])                            
                        ->where('property_id ', $property)->get();

$period = CarbonPeriod::create($initDate, $endDate);

// Iterate over the date range
foreach ($period as $date) {
    // if the date doesn't already exist in DB..
    if (! Calendar::where('date', '=', $date)->first() ) {
 
        // create an entry (or add something to your collection, whatever you want; $date will be missing date...
        Calendar::create( ... );
        $res->append( ... );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that. I excute this query for every property (1000+-), and ranges can be very big = a lot of querys :(

Comment: I don't need to create new lines in the calendar, just include them in the current collection. Although an array with the data would already do the job.